# cannot save value after changing the orientation in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

i am trying save value while rotating device using onsaveinstancestate and onrestoreinstancestate but when i try to fetch data in oncreate after orientation it always returns null.below is my code

```
   @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
   outState.putString("driverscore",mdriverscore.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("lastevent",recentevent.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("rashdrivingcounttext",rdcount.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("prespeedlimitcounttext",pslcount.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("corneringcounttext",cornering.getText().toString());
    outState.putInt("rashdrivingcount",mrdcount);
    outState.putInt("prespeedlimitcount",mpslcount);
    outState.putInt("corneringcount",mcornering);
    outState.putInt("newrdcount",scorerd);
    outState.putInt("newpslcount",scorepsl);
    outState.putInt("newcornercount",scorecorner);
    outState.putInt("distance",distance);
    outState.putBoolean("istripinprogress",istripinprogress);
    outState.putBoolean("ispersonidle",ispersonidle);
}
     @Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    mdriverscore.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("driverscore"));
    recentevent.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("lastevent"));
    rdcount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("rashdrivingcounttext"));
    pslcount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("prespeedlimitcounttext"));
    cornering.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("corneringcounttext"));
    mrdcount = savedInstanceState.getInt("rashdrivingcount");
    mpslcount = savedInstanceState.getInt("prespeedlimitcount");
    mcornering = savedInstanceState.getInt("corneringcount");
    scorerd = savedInstanceState.getInt("newrdcount");
    scorepsl = savedInstanceState.getInt("newpslcount");
    scorecorner = savedInstanceState.getInt("newcornercount");
    distance = savedInstanceState.getInt("distance");
    istripinprogress =savedInstanceState.getBoolean("istripinprogress");
    ispersonidle = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ispersonidle");
}
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newxml);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        istripinprogress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("istripinprogress");
        ispersonidle = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ispersonidle");
        mrdcount =savedInstanceState.getInt("rashdrivingcount");
    }
```

mrdcount returns null istripinprogress and ispersonidle returns default value not saved value

Comment: Try to add this two property in your manifest file activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)`

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))

`void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)`

> This is the same as onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) but is called for
>   activities created with the attribute persistableMode set to
>   persistAcrossReboots.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you are using

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
```

and not

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

Please use single parameter functions i.e.  `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and  `public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and then your `onCreate` will be able to have values from bundle.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

onRestoreInstanceState is redundant because you can easily restore state in onCreate.

```
     @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putString("driverscore",mdriverscore.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("lastevent",recentevent.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("rashdrivingcounttext",rdcount.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("prespeedlimitcounttext",pslcount.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("corneringcounttext",cornering.getText().toString());
        outState.putInt("rashdrivingcount",mrdcount);
        outState.putInt("prespeedlimitcount",mpslcount);
        outState.putInt("corneringcount",mcornering);
        outState.putInt("newrdcount",scorerd);
        outState.putInt("newpslcount",scorepsl);
        outState.putInt("newcornercount",scorecorner);
        outState.putInt("distance",distance);
        outState.putBoolean("istripinprogress",istripinprogress);
        outState.putBoolean("ispersonidle",ispersonidle);
    }

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newxml);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
 mdriverscore.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("driverscore"));
        recentevent.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("lastevent"));
        rdcount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("rashdrivingcounttext"));
        pslcount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("prespeedlimitcounttext"));
        cornering.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("corneringcounttext"));
        mrdcount = savedInstanceState.getInt("rashdrivingcount");
        mpslcount = savedInstanceState.getInt("prespeedlimitcount");
        mcornering = savedInstanceState.getInt("corneringcount");
        scorerd = savedInstanceState.getInt("newrdcount");
        scorepsl = savedInstanceState.getInt("newpslcount");
        scorecorner = savedInstanceState.getInt("newcornercount");
        distance = savedInstanceState.getInt("distance");
            istripinprogress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("istripinprogress");
            ispersonidle = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ispersonidle");


               mrdcount =savedInstanceState.getInt("rashdrivingcount");
            }
}
```

here is what the official doc says for onRestoreInstanceState:

Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation.